# R: Subsetting a data frame using a list of dates as the filter

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a date column and some other value columns. I would like to extract from the data frame those rows in which the date column matches any of the elements in a pre-existing list of dates. For example, using a list of one element, the date '2012-01-01' would pull the row with a date of '2012-01-01' from the data frame.

For numbers I think I know how to match the values. This code:

```
testdf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), 
                                  as.Date('2012-01-10'), by = 'day'),
                     col1 = 1:10,
                     col2 = 11:20,
                     col3 = 21:30)
```

...produces this data frame:

```
       mydate col1 col2 col3
1  2012-01-01    1   11   21
2  2012-01-02    2   12   22
3  2012-01-03    3   13   23
4  2012-01-04    4   14   24
5  2012-01-05    5   15   25
6  2012-01-06    6   16   26
7  2012-01-07    7   17   27
8  2012-01-08    8   18   28
9  2012-01-09    9   19   29
10 2012-01-10   10   20   30
```

I can do this:

```
testdf[which(testdf$col3 %in% c('25','29')),]
```

which produces this:

```
      mydate col1 col2 col3
5 2012-01-05    5   15   25
9 2012-01-09    9   19   29
```

I can generalise this to a list like this:

```
myvalues <- c('25','29')
testdf[which(testdf$col3 %in% myvalues),]
```

And I get the same output. So I had thought I would be able to use the same approach for dates, but it appears that I was wrong. Doing this:

```
testdf[which(testdf$mydate %in% c('2012-01-05','2012-01-09')),]
```

Gets me this:

```
[1] mydate col1   col2   col3  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

And popping the dates in their own list - which is the ultimate aim - doesn't help either. I can think of ways round this with loops or an apply function, but it seems to me that there must be a simpler way for what is probably a fairly common requirement. Is it that I have again overlooked something simple?

**Q: How can I subset those rows of a data frame that have a date column the values of which match one of a list of dates?**

Comment: I actually learnt sub-setting from your question. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I require values between 25 and 29 mean it should show 25,26,27,28,29 values of col3 using the same code testdf[which(testdf$mydate %in% .....)),] but how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to convert the date `string` into a `Date` variable using `as.Date` (try `?as.Date` at the console). Bonus: you can drop which:

```
> testdf[testdf$mydate %in% as.Date(c('2012-01-05', '2012-01-09')),]
      mydate col1 col2 col3
5 2012-01-05    5   15   25
9 2012-01-09    9   19   29
```

Comment: Thanks, I did consider conversion to string, but the docs for `match` say "Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors" and dates are not explicitly mentioned as an exception so I just assumed it would be OK. Not so...

Answer (score 11):

Both suggestions so far are definitely good, but if you are going to be doing a lot of work with dates, you may want to invest some time with the `xts` package:

```
# Some sample data for 90 consecutive days 
set.seed(1)
testdf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), 
                                  length.out=90, by = 'day'),
                     col1 = rnorm(90), col2 = rnorm(90),
                     col3 = rnorm(90))

# Convert the data to an xts object
require(xts)
testdfx = xts(testdf, order.by=testdf$mydate)

# Take a random sample of dates
testdfx[sample(index(testdfx), 5)]
#                   col1        col2        col3
# 2012-01-17 -0.01619026  0.71670748  1.44115771
# 2012-01-29 -0.47815006  0.49418833 -0.01339952
# 2012-02-05 -0.41499456  0.71266631  1.51974503
# 2012-02-27 -1.04413463  0.01739562 -1.18645864
# 2012-03-26  0.33295037 -0.03472603  0.27005490

# Get specific dates
testdfx[c('2012-01-05', '2012-01-09')]
#                 col1      col2       col3
# 2012-01-05 0.3295078  1.586833  0.5210227
# 2012-01-09 0.5757814 -1.224613 -0.4302118
```

You can also get dates from another vector.

```
# Get dates from another vector
lookup = c("2012-01-12", "2012-01-31", "2012-03-05", "2012-03-19")
testdfx[lookup]
testdfx[lookup]
#                   col1        col2       col3
# 2012-01-12  0.38984324  0.04211587  0.4020118
# 2012-01-31  1.35867955 -0.50595746 -0.1643758
# 2012-03-05 -0.74327321 -1.48746031  1.1629646
# 2012-03-19  0.07434132 -0.14439960  0.3747244
```

The `xts` package will give you intelligent subsetting options. For instance, `testdfx["2012-03"]` will return all the data from March; `testdfx["2012"]` will return for the year; `testdfx["/2012-02-15"]` will return the data from the start of the dataset to February 15; and `testdfx["2012-02-15/"]` will go from February 15 to the end of the dataset.

Comment: I do use `xts` every day but I had forgotten about those little extras so +1 for the useful reminder

Answer (score 3):

Or you can go the other way round to what @RYogi suggested and convert the `Date` into a string:

```
testdf[as.character(testdf$mydate) %in% c('2012-01-05', '2012-01-09'),]
      mydate col1 col2 col3
5 2012-01-05    5   15   25
9 2012-01-09    9   19   29
```

## Edit: timing

Converting Date to a string is slightly faster, but it doesn't really make a difference:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(asDate=testdf[testdf$mydate %in% as.Date(c('2012-01-05', '2012-01-09')),],
  asString=testdf[as.character(testdf$mydate) %in% c('2012-01-05', '2012-01-09'),], 
  replications=1000)

#     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
# 1   asDate         1000   0.211 1.076531     0.212        0          0
# 2 asString         1000   0.196 1.000000     0.192        0          0
#  sys.child
# 1         0
# 2         0
```

Comment: Converting to `Date` is probably more expensive computationally, but in this case the number of conversions should be smaller.

Comment: @jmsigner thank you for this - I find them equally useful but the other answer was just a little quicker.