# Subset xts object using vector of unique index days

Tags: r, indexing, subset, xts

I'm trying to subset an xts object using a vector of `xts` timestamps that have been processed into a vector of unique timestamps. This follows on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555588/test-if-variables-within-a-time-of-day-subset-meet-conditions-and-return-non-su?noredirect=1#comment22145387_15555588) previous question that was only partially answered.

**Some sample data:**

```
dput(sample.data.merge, control="all")

structure(c(11.65, 11.13, 11.13, 11.5, 11.8, 11.45, 11.45, 11.08, 
11.08, 11.25, 9.8, 10.45, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 10.9, 
10.45, 10.5, 10.5, 10.08, 10.08, 10.65, 10.08, 10.65, 10.6, 10.65, 
10.65, 10.085, 10.145, 11.9, 11.085, 9.35, 9.15, 9.15, 9.9, 9.0875, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.35, 9.35, 9.35, 9.25, 9.5, 9.45, 9.3, 11.15, 
11.15, 11.15, 11.15, 11.8, 8, 10.05, 10.05, 10.25, 10.4, 10.15, 
10.15, 10.3, 10.15, 10.1, 11.08, 11.08, 11.08, 11.65, 11.85, 
11.9, 11.9, 11.9, 12.65, 13.35, 13.35, 15.95, 15.9, 15.4, 15.4, 
15.4, 15.4, 15.13, 12.13, 12.35, 11.082, 11.082, 11.08, 12.1, 
12.3, 12.3, 12.4, 12.6, 12.6, 12.13, 12.45, 12.9, 12.9, 12.9, 
14, 12.6, 12.6, 12.45, 15.25, 12.085, 12.95, 12.95, 12.35, 12.13, 
12.8, 14, 14, 12.45, 12.45, 12.45, 12.45, 12.25, 12.6, 12.085, 
15.1, 15.15, 15.35, 15.3, 12.5, 12.5, 12.15, 12.2, 11.085, 11.35, 
11.45, 11.13, 11.13, 11.35, 11.2, 12.5, 12.6, 12.95, 12.95, 12.5, 
12.45, 12.3, 12.3, 12.3, 12.45, 12.45, 12.45, 12.5, 12.45, 12.45, 
12.13, 12.13, 12.65, 190, 190, 190, 190, 130, 190, 190, 190, 
190, 190, 130, 190, 130, 130, 445, 445, 445, 445, 130, 445, 190, 
445, 445, 190, 190, 190, 190, 130, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 
190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 
190, 275, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 130, 130, 
190, 190, 190, 130, 130, 130, 190, 130, 190, 190, 190, 130, 190, 
190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 
1190, 190, 190, 130, 130, 130, 190, 1130, 190, 190, 130, 190, 
190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 130, 130, 190, 190, 375, 190, 190, 190, 
130, 190, 130, 190, 190, 190, 190, 130, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 
190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 
130, 130, 130, 190, 130, 190, 190, 190, 130, 130, 445, 445, 130, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.21, 0.21, 0.26, 0.0250000000000004, 
0, 0.0250000000000004, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.0249999999999995, 0.0250000000000004, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0250000000000004, 
0.100000000000001, 0.39, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0250000000000004, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.524999999999999, 0.25, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.149999999999999, 0.135000000000001, 
0.149999999999999, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.409999999999999, 0.375, 0.3, 0.635, 0.385, 0.335, 0.175000000000001, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.4, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.109999999999999, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.0749999999999993, 0.0749999999999993, 0.0749999999999993, 
0.0250000000000004, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 127.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30, 30, 30, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 30, 30, 30, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, 30, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 30, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.9, 
10.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.29, 10.29, 10.34, 10.625, 10.65, 
10.625, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.325, 
9.325, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.15, 10.225, 10.69, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.9, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.4, 15.4, 15.4, 15.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.35, 12.35, 12.425, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.65, 12.575, 12.875, 12.875, 12.625, 
12.625, 12.625, 12.45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.85, 15.125, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.275, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.375, 12.375, 12.375, 12.45, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 445, 445, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 317.5, 190, 190, 190, 190, 
190, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 190, 
190, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 160, 160, 160, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 190, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 190, 190, 190, 190, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 160, 160, 160, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 190, 190, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 190, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 130, 130, 160, 190, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NaN, Inf, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.999999999999996, 
1.71428571428572, 1, 1, NaN, 21.5999999999997, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.00000000000004, 2.99999999999993, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 37.1999999999995, 8.54999999999987, 0.999999999999998, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29.9999999999996, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
0, NaN, Inf, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.66666666666666, 
1.62962962962963, 0.166666666666658, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.26829268292683, 0.600000000000004, 
3.75, 1.77165354330709, 0.454545454545457, 0.522388059701495, 
1, NaN, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.07142857142857, 0.875000000000003, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.681818181818179, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NaN, Inf, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NaN, NaN, Inf, NaN, NaN, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, Inf, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
1, 32.3333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NaN, 6.16666666666667, 0, NaN, NaN, Inf, NaN, Inf, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NaN, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NaN, Inf, 1, NaN, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(150L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("price", "volume", "madprice", "madvolume", "medianprice", 
    "medianvolume", "absdevmadprice", "absdevmadvolume")), index = structure(c(1325584080, 
1325594940, 1325594940, 1325604600, 1325759100, 1325762520, 1325762520, 
1325769300, 1325769300, 1325848080, 1325864880, 1326128220, 1326196500, 
1326196500, 1326196500, 1326196500, 1326196500, 1326196500, 1326209700, 
1326279480, 1326283620, 1326288300, 1326288300, 1326289680, 1326289680, 
1326289680, 1326292320, 1326294060, 1326294600, 1326297600, 1326387000, 
1326456720, 1326467160, 1326711600, 1326723000, 1326724260, 1326809940, 
1326814860, 1326885960, 1326885960, 1326889980, 1326894000, 1326895200, 
1326895200, 1326898080, 1326986700, 1326987240, 1326992100, 1327072140, 
1327328040, 1327328040, 1327328040, 1327417920, 1327423140, 1327424820, 
1327425240, 1327483200, 1327496520, 1327570320, 1327570320, 1327575420, 
1327588680, 1327588980, 1327595880, 1327595880, 1327595880, 1327664820, 
1327674720, 1327680660, 1327680780, 1327680780, 1327683960, 1327914300, 
1327914300, 1327915260, 1327918140, 1327924860, 1327924920, 1327924980, 
1327924980, 1327927680, 1328013360, 1328014200, 1328025000, 1328025000, 
1328026740, 1328089440, 1328091360, 1328091360, 1328110620, 1328111340, 
1328111340, 1328112420, 1328113800, 1328193540, 1328194080, 1328194140, 
1328196720, 1328274360, 1328274420, 1328278320, 1328519280, 1328520120, 
1328520600, 1328520600, 1328524140, 1328527980, 1328531580, 1328540880, 
1328540880, 1328547600, 1328547660, 1328547720, 1328547780, 1328607060, 
1328608080, 1328618760, 1328623380, 1328623380, 1328625720, 1328631480, 
1328717760, 1328717880, 1328793000, 1328797980, 1329132840, 1329210480, 
1329215400, 1329215820, 1329215820, 1329219480, 1329223140, 1329300900, 
1329301620, 1329315240, 1329315240, 1329388740, 1329389700, 1329390000, 
1329390000, 1329390180, 1329391860, 1329391860, 1329391860, 1329402120, 
1329467700, 1329467700, 1329469080, 1329469080, 1329471300), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

**The code:**

```
sample.data.mergesub <- sample.data.merge['T10:30/T17:30']
sample.data.mergeout <- sample.data.mergesub[ which((sample.data.mergesub$absdevmadprice >=5 & sample.data.mergesub$absdevmadprice < Inf) | (sample.data.mergesub$absdevmadvol>=10 & sample.data.mergesub$absdevmadvol<Inf)),]
sample.data.unique <- unique(.indexday(sample.data.mergeout))
```

This `sample.data.unique` is therefore a vector of index days. **Question:** I'd like to use this to extract the full day of data from the original dataset `sample.data` in order to later graph the full day of trades, rather than the subset of data. For instance, if Jan 03 2012 10:53:00 meets the conditions of having absdevmadprice >= 5, and less than infinite, then I'd like to return the day (Jan 03 2012) into a vector and use this to subset the original dataset. This would select all observations in that day (so over the whole trading period) and I could then graph this day.

I've tried this code (based on Joshua's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101694/subsetting-in-xts-using-a-parameter-holding-dates)) but it doesn't work:

```
> sample.data.uniquePOS<-sample.data.merge[paste(as.Date(as.POSIXct(sample.data.unique, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC", tz="GMT")))]
```

It returns simply the column names:

```
> sample.data.uniquePOS
price volume madprice madvolume medianprice medianvolume absdevmadprice
     absdevmadvolume
```

For info, the structure of the variables:

```
> str(sample.data.merge)
An ‘xts’ object on 2012-01-03 09:48:00/2012-02-17 09:35:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:150, 1:8] 11.6 11.1 11.1 11.5 11.8 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:8] "price" "volume" "madprice" "madvolume" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXlt,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

> str(sample.data.uniquePOS)
An 'xts' object of zero-width

> str(sample.data.unique)
 num 15371
```

Thanks for the help (and if anyone can explain why the code doesn't work!).

Comment: No need to duplicate your question. I suggest that you delete your previous one.

Comment: I managed to solve it now with this code. Will post it as an answer when SO allows me to. sample.data.uniquePOS <- sample.data.merge[paste(as.Date.numeric(sample.data.unique, origin= "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC", tz="GMT")),]

Comment: Can you add more meaningful sample data. The sample data you have added has NA for `absdevmadprice ` and `absdevmadvol` for ` sample.data.mergesub` ?

Comment: @geektrader There are many NAs because of the rolling nature of the runMAD and runMedian, but 'sample.data.mergesub' does have some non-NA data in it. Can you check that the 'sample.data.mergesub' subset uses a 10:30-17:30 window? When I first posted it the window was just a few minutes by mistake, and I changed it immediately - but it's still possible you copied it before the changes were made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## answer to own question:

Using these posts (Ananda's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464578/r-subsetting-a-data-frame-using-a-list-of-dates-as-the-filter/11466229#11466229), Joshua's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101694/subsetting-in-xts-using-a-parameter-holding-dates), and the `as.Date.numeric` function I found out about [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-March/233159.html)) I was able to solve my own problem. This line of code seems to do it:

```
sample.data.uniquePOS <- sample.data.merge[paste(as.Date.numeric(sample.data.unique, origin= "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC", tz="GMT")),]
```

Can't give a great explanation as to why it works compared to the below, but perhaps `as.POSIXct` can't take the same format that `as.Date.numeric` can?

```
sample.data.uniquePOS <- sample.data.merge[paste(as.Date(as.POSIXct(sample.data.unique, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC", tz="GMT")))]
```

Comment: You don't need `as.Date.numeric`. `as.Date` works just fine. `as.POSIXct` doesn't work because `sample.data.unique` is a numeric vector of days since the origin (`Date`), not seconds since the origin (`POSIXt`).