# Automatically plot (and save) list of xts objects

Tags: r, list, plot, xts, quantmod

I have a long list of `xts` objects and I'd like to automatically plot and save them to a folder (because it takes a v long time to do manually with >500 plots). The tricky part seems to be to apply functions to lists of `xts` objects. For example, getting a generalized naming method for the list elements based on its date (each `xts` object in the list is a unique day), and plotting each object and saving them to a file path with its own name.

**The data** can be found in a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620935/subset-xts-object-using-vector-of-unique-index-days). Each `xts` element is a unique day in the list, with a price and volume column. I'm using the packages xts, TTR, and quantmod with the latest R (2.15).

I've tried this code to name the list elements, based on a great [post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/) on r-bloggers:

```
names(sample.data.uniquePOS) <- paste0("sample.data.uniquePOS", lapply(sample.data.uniquePOS, function(x) .indexday(sample.data.uniquePOS)))
```

This is supposed to name them by their day index (e.g. if 1st January 2012 then it would be "2012-01-01" as the element name). Unfortunately it doesn't work, producing a list of length `sample.data.uniquePOS` but each element is named `sample.data.uniquePOSnumeric(0)`. I think the problem is the `.indexday` being applied to a list, when it should be to an `xts` object, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

The next step is to produce the file path to save the plots to, and then to do the plots:

```
mypath <- file.path("C:", "Documents and Settings", 
                              paste("Date_", names(sample.data.uniquePOS), ".jpg", sep = ""))

jpg(file=mypath)
mytitle = paste("my title is", names(sample.data.uniquePOS))
candleChart(sample.data.uniquePOS[[1]]:sample.data.uniquePOS[[length(sample.data.uniquePOS)]])
dev.off()
}
```

This has the same problem of `candleChart` needing to be applied to an `xts` object instead of a list:

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this!

Comment: `jpg` and `candleChart` are not vectorized. Use a loop over your list.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich This loop seems to work for the candleChart - `plots1<- lapply(sample.data.uniquePOS, candleChart)`, but then `lapply(plots1, jpg(file=mypath)` (or `jpeg(...)`) returns the error `Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  jpeg(file = mypath) is not a function, character or symbol`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Also tried this `lapply(names(sample.data.uniquePOS), function(x) dev.copy2pdf(filename=mypath), candleChart=sample.data.uniquePOS[[x]])` but it returned "list()", and not sure what that means. Also tried a loop: `for (i in 1:length(sample.data.uniquePOS)) {filename=paste("Main_", names(sample.data.uniquePOS), ".jpg", sep = "")  jpeg(filename)  candleChart}` but it created a single jpeg (when there should be as many jpegs as xts objects) with nothing in it.