# subset from a data.frame based on a date time colum

Tags: date, dataframe, subset

I have the following data.frame with about 18 millions of records

```
        Gender Age Bici DepartingSta        DateTimeDepa ArrivingSta        DateTimeArri TravelTime
    1      M  28   69           85 2010-02-16 12:42:32          85 2010-02-16 12:45:37        3.1
    2      M  30   11           85 2010-02-16 12:53:29          26 2010-02-16 13:22:23       28.9
    3      M  37   43           85 2010-02-16 13:21:46          13 2010-02-16 13:49:47       28.0
    4      M  37  826           22 2010-02-16 14:06:40          85 2010-02-16 14:23:13       16.6
    5      M  19  662           27 2010-02-16 15:31:15          74 2010-02-16 16:29:17       58.0
    6      F  25    8           85 2010-02-16 16:31:53          20 2010-02-16 16:49:26       17.6
17919307      F  26 2760          121 2015-01-30 23:58:33         106 2015-01-31 00:22:08       23.6
17919308      M  22 4077           71 2015-01-30 23:58:50         190 2015-01-31 00:13:24       14.6
17919309      M  32  699          154 2015-01-30 23:58:55         165 2015-01-31 00:02:25        3.5
17919310      F  26 4044           64 2015-01-30 23:59:20          50 2015-01-31 00:05:38        6.3
17919311      M  26 3114           26 2015-01-30 23:59:23         127 2015-01-31 00:12:29       13.1
17919312      M  25 4115          165 2015-01-30 23:59:55          73 2015-01-31 00:12:39       12.7
```

I want to write a function to `subset` the trips from January 2015. The input is `"201501"` and the results is

```
 Gender Age Bici DepartingSta        DateTimeDepa ArrivingSta        DateTimeArri TravelTime
17919307      F  26 2760          121 2015-01-30 23:58:33         106 2015-01-31 00:22:08       23.6
17919308      M  22 4077           71 2015-01-30 23:58:50         190 2015-01-31 00:13:24       14.6
17919309      M  32  699          154 2015-01-30 23:58:55         165 2015-01-31 00:02:25        3.5
17919310      F  26 4044           64 2015-01-30 23:59:20          50 2015-01-31 00:05:38        6.3
17919311      M  26 3114           26 2015-01-30 23:59:23         127 2015-01-31 00:12:29       13.1
17919312      M  25 4115          165 2015-01-30 23:59:55          73 2015-01-31 00:12:39       12.7
```

Comment: Do you want to filter on `DateTimeDepa` or `DateTimeArri` ? I'm saying this because one flight could depart on `2015-01-31 23:00:00` and arrive at `2015-02-01 1:00:00`

Comment: Great Question, Just the DateTimeDepa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464578/r-subsetting-a-data-frame-using-a-list-of-dates-as-the-filter/11466229#11466229), you could convert your dataset into an `xts` object and then use intelligent subsetting options:

```
xtsdf <- xts::xts(df, order.by = df$DateTimeDepa)
xtsdf["201501"]
```

Which gives:

```
#                    Gender Age  Bici   DepartingSta DateTimeDepa          #ArrivingSta
#2015-01-30 23:58:33 "F"    "26" "2760" "121"        "2015-01-30 23:58:33" "106"      
#2015-01-30 23:58:50 "M"    "22" "4077" " 71"        "2015-01-30 23:58:50" "190"      
#2015-01-30 23:58:55 "M"    "32" " 699" "154"        "2015-01-30 23:58:55" "165"      
#2015-01-30 23:59:20 "F"    "26" "4044" " 64"        "2015-01-30 23:59:20" " 50"      
#2015-01-30 23:59:23 "M"    "26" "3114" " 26"        "2015-01-30 23:59:23" "127"      
#2015-01-30 23:59:55 "M"    "25" "4115" "165"        "2015-01-30 23:59:55" " 73"      
#                    DateTimeArri          TravelTime
#2015-01-30 23:58:33 "2015-01-31 00:22:08" "23.6"    
#2015-01-30 23:58:50 "2015-01-31 00:13:24" "14.6"    
#2015-01-30 23:58:55 "2015-01-31 00:02:25" " 3.5"    
#2015-01-30 23:59:20 "2015-01-31 00:05:38" " 6.3"    
#2015-01-30 23:59:23 "2015-01-31 00:12:29" "13.1"    
#2015-01-30 23:59:55 "2015-01-31 00:12:39" "12.7"
```

Comment: Works perfect to me Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can solve this using base R [`format()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/format.html), vectorized string comparison, and [`subset()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html):

```
df <- data.frame(Gender=c('M','M','M','M','M','F','F','M','M','F','M','M'),Age=c(28L,30L,37L,37L,19L,25L,26L,22L,32L,26L,26L,25L),Bici=c(69L,11L,43L,826L,662L,8L,2760L,4077L,699L,4044L,3114L,4115L),DepartingSta=c(85L,85L,85L,22L,27L,85L,121L,71L,154L,64L,26L,165L),DateTimeDepa=as.POSIXct(c('2010-02-16 12:42:32','2010-02-16 12:53:29','2010-02-16 13:21:46','2010-02-16 14:06:40','2010-02-16 15:31:15','2010-02-16 16:31:53','2015-01-30 23:58:33','2015-01-30 23:58:50','2015-01-30 23:58:55','2015-01-30 23:59:20','2015-01-30 23:59:23','2015-01-30 23:59:55')),ArrivingSta=c(85L,26L,13L,85L,74L,20L,106L,190L,165L,50L,127L,73L),DateTimeArri=as.POSIXct(c('2010-02-16 12:45:37','2010-02-16 13:22:23','2010-02-16 13:49:47','2010-02-16 14:23:13','2010-02-16 16:29:17','2010-02-16 16:49:26','2015-01-31 00:22:08','2015-01-31 00:13:24','2015-01-31 00:02:25','2015-01-31 00:05:38','2015-01-31 00:12:29','2015-01-31 00:12:39')),TravelTime=c(3.1,28.9,28,16.6,58,17.6,23.6,14.6,3.5,6.3,13.1,12.7),row.names=c('1','2','3','4','5','6','17919307','17919308','17919309','17919310','17919311','17919312'),stringsAsFactors=F);
ym <- '201501';
```

---

```
df;
##          Gender Age Bici DepartingSta        DateTimeDepa ArrivingSta        DateTimeArri TravelTime
## 1             M  28   69           85 2010-02-16 12:42:32          85 2010-02-16 12:45:37        3.1
## 2             M  30   11           85 2010-02-16 12:53:29          26 2010-02-16 13:22:23       28.9
## 3             M  37   43           85 2010-02-16 13:21:46          13 2010-02-16 13:49:47       28.0
## 4             M  37  826           22 2010-02-16 14:06:40          85 2010-02-16 14:23:13       16.6
## 5             M  19  662           27 2010-02-16 15:31:15          74 2010-02-16 16:29:17       58.0
## 6             F  25    8           85 2010-02-16 16:31:53          20 2010-02-16 16:49:26       17.6
## 17919307      F  26 2760          121 2015-01-30 23:58:33         106 2015-01-31 00:22:08       23.6
## 17919308      M  22 4077           71 2015-01-30 23:58:50         190 2015-01-31 00:13:24       14.6
## 17919309      M  32  699          154 2015-01-30 23:58:55         165 2015-01-31 00:02:25        3.5
## 17919310      F  26 4044           64 2015-01-30 23:59:20          50 2015-01-31 00:05:38        6.3
## 17919311      M  26 3114           26 2015-01-30 23:59:23         127 2015-01-31 00:12:29       13.1
## 17919312      M  25 4115          165 2015-01-30 23:59:55          73 2015-01-31 00:12:39       12.7
ym;
## [1] "201501"
```

---

```
subset(df,format(DateTimeDepa,'%Y%m')==ym);
##          Gender Age Bici DepartingSta        DateTimeDepa ArrivingSta        DateTimeArri TravelTime
## 17919307      F  26 2760          121 2015-01-30 23:58:33         106 2015-01-31 00:22:08       23.6
## 17919308      M  22 4077           71 2015-01-30 23:58:50         190 2015-01-31 00:13:24       14.6
## 17919309      M  32  699          154 2015-01-30 23:58:55         165 2015-01-31 00:02:25        3.5
## 17919310      F  26 4044           64 2015-01-30 23:59:20          50 2015-01-31 00:05:38        6.3
## 17919311      M  26 3114           26 2015-01-30 23:59:23         127 2015-01-31 00:12:29       13.1
## 17919312      M  25 4115          165 2015-01-30 23:59:55          73 2015-01-31 00:12:39       12.7
```