# Subset data frame using date ranges as filters and a grouping variable in R

Tags: r, date, select, subset

**I don't think this is a duplicate question of [Range join data.frames - specific date column with date ranges/intervals in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371747/range-join-data-frames-specific-date-column-with-date-ranges-intervals-in-r)** because I am not looking to merge data frames BUT to delete from a data frame all the records that are outside time frames that I have specified in another data frame.

Specifically, I want to select records grouped by the variable `id_time`, in a file that looks like the one below `hr`, using the date periods in a second file `dates` that has the time period of interest for each `id_time`.

The file `hr` originally has >1000 rows, each row is an observation that belongs to an individual `id_time`, and each observation has the date it was recorded in `Local date`. There are many observations per individual, each with different dates. Roughly this file looks like this:

```
hr<-read.table(text = 
                     "id_time   season  sex Local_date  Area(ha)
                   10C_MTHM Late_dry    M   2015/09/01  12231.49898
                   10C_MTHM Late_dry    M   2015/10/31  15883.57836
                   10C_MTHM Wet         M   2015/11/30  2725.42549
                   10C_MTHM Wet         M   2015/12/31  40743.25861
                   10C_MTHM Wet         M   2016/01/31  44685.19565
                   10C_MTHM Wet         M   2016/02/26  21313.59966
                   10C_MTHM Wet         M   2014/12/31  36782.41615
                   10C_MTHM Wet         M   2015/01/31  126159.3232
                   10C_MTHM Wet         M   2015/02/28  113034.0324
                   10C_MTHM Early_dry   M   2015/03/31  50179.50564
                   10C_MTHM Early_dry   M   2015/04/30  29744.83677
                   10C_MTHM Early_dry   M   2015/05/31  33990.54416
                   10C_MTHM Early_dry   M   2015/06/30  31081.3867
                   10E_CHIM2    Late_dry    M   2015/09/30  5467.727522
                   10E_CHIM2    Late_dry    M   2015/10/31  925.188892
                   10E_CHIM2    Wet         M   2015/11/30  4663.484598
                   10E_CHIM2    Wet         M   2015/12/31  18767.86083
                   10E_CHIM2    Wet         M   2016/01/31  25163.76076
                   10E_CHIM2    Wet         M   2016/02/26  40432.86667
                   10E_CHIM2    Late_dry    M   2014/09/30  12403.64243
                   10E_CHIM2    Late_dry    M   2014/10/31  15391.80744
                   11C_SDBM Late_dry    M   2015/07/31  292012.0909
                   11C_SDBM Late_dry    M   2015/08/31  149293.0196
                   11C_SDBM Late_dry    M   2015/09/30  88775.83245
                   11C_SDBM Late_dry    M   2015/10/31  20980.49625
                   11C_SDBM Wet         M   2015/11/30  44679.24235
                   11C_SDBM Wet         M   2015/12/31  85124.26871
                   11C_SDBM Wet         M   2016/01/31  4573.904479",
                   header = TRUE)
```

The second file `dates` has only a few rows, and the only information here is a range of dates for each individual `id time` that appears in the `hr` file. This `dates` file, with the date ranges, is the one I want R to use to select all the rows with dates within each date range of the respective individual `id_time`, deleting all the other rows for which the dates are outside the specific period:

```
dates<-read.table(text = 
                    "date_id    start_date  end_date
                    10C_MTHM    2015/02/24  2016/02/24
                    11C_SDBM    2015/01/01  2015/06/30
                    10E_CHIM2   2015/01/01  2016/01/01",
                                        header = TRUE)
```

My intended outcome is the hr file (just one file) WITH all the records for each individual `id_time` for which dates fall within the period of interest shown in the `dates` file. All the rest of the records for each individual outside the time period of interested should be deleted in the output.

For example for the first individual 10C_MTHM, I would like the final database to include only the records of this individual that are within 2015/02/24    and 2016/02/24, as specified in the `dates` file. And so forth with each individual. All these records in one single database.

I found a question similar to this but the difference is that my date ranges are not in a column in the same file but in a second file [R: Subsetting a data frame using a list of dates as the filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464578/r-subsetting-a-data-frame-using-a-list-of-dates-as-the-filter)

How would I create a code to select records based on the information specified in a different file?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is your intended outcome? Do you want separate data.frames for each date interval? Do you want to construct a grouping variable? Please include an example of your intended outcome in your question.

Comment: I believe there is a more modern solution to this: `setkey(hr,id_time);
setkey(dates,date_id);
hr[dates][anywhere(Local_date, start_date, end_date)]` using the dev version of `data.table`.

Comment: @lmo I have edited my question to make it clearer. I hope this clarification helps.

Comment: [roll join with start/end window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031)